# Jenkins job takes a long time to complete after it prints "finished"

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, multi-configuration

I have a case when running a matrix job, once it prints "Finished: SUCCESS", it sits there spinning for a long time (~15-20 mins) before the job actually tears down and completes. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: I also have the same issue. It takes usually 5-10 minutes to completion.

Comment: I tried reducing the number of logs that are kept to 100 and removed a plugin called disk usage plugin. That seemed to help a bit.

Comment: It's good to add "Calcualete disk usage pluging" as a a post-build action. The solution is mentioned here: [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24829](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24829)